# WPF and data in the cloud

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to create a WPF app that users will use on one machine and the manager wishes to use at home in the evenings. I have already suggested a web app which they don't want to do so suggested hosting the data in the cloud.

I haven't used this scenario before so I wanted to take the time to see what other people would suggest on here as an alternative to my suggestion which is essentially a connection string to an external sql server source.

They don't want a web app nor do they have a network there (very small place, only 2 computers), however I am concerned about any internet issues that will effectively stop any data transactions and thus the app itself.

I am happy to hear any alternatives to data source, synchronization etc as I'm happy to take the time to learn something different if it makes the end product better.

Comment: Why don't they want a web app?  It would be easier, cheaper, and more secure than most likely alternatives.

Comment: I know :( 
I think they have a poor internet connection and thats why, would have a similar problem with system being unavailable if goes down as well which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Does the database exists in a Sql Server Database already? or is this a new project from scratch?

Comment: @EdMendez Nothing exists as yet, new project from scratch which is why I'm asking for others opinions before I proceed

Comment: @DanPichelman Web apps are not cheaper than desktop to build and maintain.

Comment: If they have a poor internet connection, cloud will also be problematic. I guess what they want to see (given their lack of technical know-how) is an old-style, single application (like the PC era of the 1990's) where data is stored locally, and occasionally backed up onto USB drives or "the cloud, whatever". If anything happens to the computer, they will lose the result of their work since the last backup. Backup and synchronization are not the same concept.

Answer (score 2):

If they are such a small company with only two computers, I would just suggest to start with VPN.  Use a VPN client to connect to the companies network resources then you can access the database remotely.  After the company grows or grows tired of VPN, a more appropriate solution could be designed.